# Getting a Null Pointer exception for a recursive tree call in Kotlin. How to fix it?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, binary-tree

I'm doing a Recursion call to print out a the values of a tree in a mutable list. But I am getting this NullPointerException error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at udacity.TreesPraticeKt.DFSRecursive(TreesPratice.kt:29)
    at udacity.TreesPraticeKt.DFSRecursive(TreesPratice.kt:29)
    at udacity.TreesPraticeKt.DFSRecursive(TreesPratice.kt:29)
    at udacity.TreesPraticeKt.main(TreesPratice.kt:63)
    at udacity.TreesPraticeKt.main(TreesPratice.kt)
```

I tried addressing it with an if statement, but it doesn't work

Here's the code

```
class TreeNode<T>(var key: T){
    var left: TreeNode<T>? = null
    var right: TreeNode<T>? = null
}

/** Recursive Function */
fun DFSRecursive(root: TreeNode<Char>) {
    if(root == null) return
    val results = mutableListOf<Char>()
    DFSRecursive(root.right!!)
    DFSRecursive(root.left!!)

    results.add(root.key)

    return println(results)

}

fun buildTree(): TreeNode<Char>{
    val a = TreeNode('a')
    val b = TreeNode('b')
    val c = TreeNode('c')
    val d = TreeNode('d')
    val e = TreeNode('e')
    val f = TreeNode('f')


    a.left = b
    a.right = c
    b.left = d
    b.right = e
    c.right = f

    return a
}
```

the Output should be:
[a, b, d, e, c, f]

But without checking for the null, it just keeps showing that error. Thank you and Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a matter of style, Kotlin coding conventions use function names that start with a lower-case letter. Using an upper-case one for `DFSRecursive()` is confusing (coz calls to it look like creating an object).

Comment: Absolutely. I was just doing that to differentiate some of the functions in the File. But you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for a `null` too late.

You shouldn't check whether `root` is `null`. That can *never happen*, because `root` is of a type `TreeNode<Char>`, not `TreeNode<Char>?`. Your IDE should issue a warning saying that:

> Condition `root == null` is always `false`

Instead of checking for `root == null`, check for `root.left` and `root.right` *before* you recurse.

Usually in Kotlin, when you encounter `NullPointerException`, you ough to look for `!!`. Most of the time the problems lie there. This is also the case here.

You should use `?.let { }` here:

```kotlin
fun DFSRecursive(root: TreeNode<Char>) {
    val results = mutableListOf<Char>()
    root.right?.let { DFSRecursive(it) }
    root.left?.let { DFSRecursive(it) }

    results.add(root.key)

    return println(results)
}
```

This change effectively recurses to the left *only* if the exists the left subree (`root.left` is not `null`) ad recurses to the right *only* if there exists the right subtree (`root.right` is not `null`).

---

After some follow-up questions, I decided to propose a modified implementation of `DFSRecursive()`:

```kotlin
fun DFSRecursive(root: TreeNode<Char>) {
    println(root.key)
    root.left?.let { DFSRecursive(it) }
    root.right?.let { DFSRecursive(it) }
}
```

The above implementation prints the elements in the *in-order* ordering (which you specified as desired) and does not have the seemingly useless list created just for one element per call.

Comment: OK. I understand. It did work, but it printed out in reverse order "the 'a' at the bottom and the order going bottom up". not sure if that's how it's supposed to print out.

Comment: @OEThe11 the difference you are describing is formally known as the *tree traversal order*. In my answer (and in your original question), the implementation demonstrates the *post-order*.  I believe what you are looking for is *in-order*.

Comment: OK. I'm definitely aware of in-order, pre-order and post-order traversals. Not sure how I did a post-order though.

Comment: @OEThe11 well, you first recursed both subtrees and only then you printed ("visited") the key. This is clearly post-order.

Comment: So, that's true. How would I now go In-Order then? I cant necessarily place the key node in the middle of the two recursive calls.

Comment: @OEThe11 please check my edit - I posted a modified solution that produces the output in in-order. Just at the end of the answer.

Comment: Ahh, so it was the mutableList That was not needed. That did complicate things. Thank you for all the help. I really appreciate that.